# Computational Complexity of Modular Exponentiation (from Rosen's Discrete Mathematics)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, algorithms, modular-arithmetic

This is a block of code from *Kenneth Rosen's Discrete Mathematics* book, for calculating $b^n \mod m$, and it says that:

> The number of bit operations should be big-O of
> $\mathcal{O} \left ( \left (\log(m) \right )^2 \cdot \log(n) \right)$.

I understand that, there are $k$ (which is the length in bits of the binary form of $n$) runs of the loop, so that there is a $\log(n)$ term, but I don't see where the $\left (\log(m) \right)^2$ term is coming from.

It seems like they are saying the two lines of the *for* loop, each perform a *modular division* with an integer $m$, whose length is $\log(m)$, but I am unsure if $(x \cdot power)$ and $(power \cdot power)$ should be considered the integer $m$. Or why they would be multiplied instead of just $2\log(m)$?

Thanks for the help!

[image: The code]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For $a\times b \equiv \bmod m$ they use a quadratic multiplication / reduction algorithm with a complexity of $O(\log(m)^2)$. Multiply this with the number of loops, i.e. $k=\log(n),$ and you get $O(\log(m)^2 \times \log(n)).$

Note that the square `power*power`is computed $k$ times, but `x*power` only $k/2$ on average (depending on the bit count of $a$).

Comment: Note that for large moduli, there are [multiplication algorithms that perform better](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_of_mathematical_operations) than the $\Theta({\it length}^2)$ of ordinary long multiplication. (But a textbooks of the headings-in-colored-ink variety probably won't assume knowledge of them).

Comment: I can see where the $log(m)^2$ comes from because the two terms need to be multiplied (and the complexity for that algorithm is $O(n^2)$, but doesn't the $\mod(m)$ operation also have some level of complexity that we need to add? I can't tell where that comes in

Comment: Yes. But normally divison or **mod** has the same complexity as multiplication, here $O(\log(n)^2),$ and therefore the complexity for one loop is $O(\log(n)^2)+O(\log(n)^2) = O(\log(n)^2),$  for more info see  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_of_mathematical_operations.
You can see (as already noted by @henning-makholm) that multiplication and/or division can be implemented better than $O(\log(n)^2),$ e.g. the Karatsuba multiplication with $O(\log(n)^{1.585}).$  Don't be confused by the Wiki table, there n is the bit-size or digit-size not the number itself.

Comment: Thank you. Since multiplication of two integers is $O(n^2)$, then why it's $O(log(m)^2)$? In worst case scenario, we would have 2 miltiplications one for $x \cdot power$ and another for $power \cdot power$, is that correct? I am really not sure why we have $log (n)$ as well.